The problem of importing a model into consumer django Websockets
I want to write a consumer for the application, however, after importing the Device model, the application does not even want to start, crashes with an error that it cannot find the application settings.
# consumers.py
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
# from devices.models import Device

class DeviceConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.device_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['device_id']
        print(self.device_id)
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.close()

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        print(message)
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'message': message}))

And here are the Device and User models:
from django.db import models
from users.models import User
from core.base.utils import generate_uuid


class Device(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    device_key = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, default=generate_uuid)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(_("first_name "), max_length=60, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("last_name "), max_length=60, blank=False)
    username = models.CharField(_("username"), max_length=60, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _("is staff"),
        default=False,
        help_text=_("Determines whether the user can log in to this administrative site."),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _("is active"),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            "Indicates whether this user should be considered active." 
"Uncheck this box instead of deleting accounts."
        ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_("дата создания"), default=now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name", "email"]


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name} ({self.username}) {self.email}"


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("user")
        verbose_name_plural = _("users")
        db_table = "users"

What could be the problem? I need to use the Device in consumer
I tried everything that the Internet offered for this error...
The error that appears at the time of adding the import:
PS D:\MyProjects\V4Control\WakeHub\backend> uvicorn core.asgi:application --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\uvicorn.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\main.py", line 409, in main
    run(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\main.py", line 575, in run
    server.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 65, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 69, in serve
    await self._serve(sockets)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 76, in _serve
    config.load()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 433, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 19, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\MyProjects\V4Control\WakeHub\backend\core\asgi.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .routing import websocket_urlpatterns
  File "D:\MyProjects\V4Control\WakeHub\backend\core\routing.py", line 3, in <module>
    from devices import consumers
  File "D:\MyProjects\V4Control\WakeHub\backend\devices\consumers.py", line 4, in <module>
    from devices.models import Device
  File "D:\MyProjects\V4Control\WakeHub\backend\devices\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from users.models import User
  File "D:\MyProjects\V4Control\WakeHub\backend\users\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 40, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 129, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 137, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 81, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 61, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
PS D:\MyProjects\V4Control\WakeHub\backend> 

Although all the settings are present in place....

The issue is in importing the settings module.
If everything is good according to you then cross check by running shell
python manage.py shell

then
from django.conf import settings
print(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

Here if you facing the error then verify the project structure again:
backend/
core/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    asgi.py
    urls.py
devices/
    models.py
    consumers.py
users/
    models.py

I hope you have configured the "core.settings" in asgi.py file
